# Is there any Gmail sdk for android, just like facebook sdk

Tags: android, gmail

Is there any Gmail sdk for android, just like facebook sdk. I don't want to use devise gmail App. can anyone help me.

Comment: [What about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/940096)

Comment: [Google API](https://developers.google.com/accounts/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such SDK and if you want to access the emails of Gmail then you need to implement your `own email client` and for that follow the above link shared by `Spk`.

**EDIT:** Android has provided a mechanism to access `Email thru it's Gmail App's content provider`.Here it is:

[The Gmail Public Labels API](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response Vineeth, but i want to access contacts of gmail with out using devise gmail app.