# Enable Gmail login in my application

Tags: android, gmail

These are the minimum details i need to login to my application:

> guid(Global Unique ID)
>
> fname
>
> lname
>
> email
>
> gender

for Facebook login it was clear and could do this:

```
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me");
```

to get all the data specified above.

Is, there a way i can do something similar and simple with Gmail?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184639/is-there-any-gmail-sdk-for-android-just-like-facebook-sdk) which says:

> No, there is no such SDK(like facebook) and if you want to access the
>   emails of Gmail then you need to implement your own email client and
>   for that follow the above link shared by Spk.

But i only want few user details, I don't need anything related to his mails etc.., which come under Authorization (if I am right). I only need Authentication:

I also read [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/), but doesn't look like it will help any.

This is the code i have now:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.GooglePlusUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 7;
    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private String TAG = "GmailLogin";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(this);
        if (errorCode != GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
            GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
        } else {

             mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
             .setVisibleActivities( "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
             "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();


            mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

            Button signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                        mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            mConnectionResult
                                    .startResolutionForResult(
                                            MainActivity.this,
                                            REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            // Try connecting again.
                            mConnectionResult = null;
                            mPlusClient.connect();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
        // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
        mConnectionResult = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR
                && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate Gmail login in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120968/how-to-integrate-gmail-login-in-android-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use Gmail for user authentication using Google accounts. You can use Google + Sign-in for Android instead. This will allow you to access the user's profile information upon getting the required permissions using OAuth. Check out the guide here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Comment: at this line `PlusClient.Builder` I get the error `PlusClient.Builder cannot be resolved to a type` everything else is fine. I imported all the packages needed

Answer (score 1):

Those attributes would be passed as [claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity) in the original authentication, as well as on each subsequent authentication.

Google [allows you to request](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) that they include up to Country, Email, First Name, Language, and Last Name as claims on the authentication token.

Since they do not provide a uuid, you will have to create one off of the email address.  There is no support (that I could find) for retrieving gender.