# How to integrate Gmail login in Android application?

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

Which is the right way to implement Gmail login in my Android application?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java
or
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/google-account-integration-in-android-login-with-gmail.html

I want to provide Gmail login for getting user credentials.Somebody please help me.

Comment: There are too many example for this....if you didn't found something good you can contact me on skype...

Comment: refer this https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Comment: could you please provide me with some examples then ?

Comment: @Nevaeh: have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official guide: [Google Login](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)

Also look at this very good tutorial with demo. Follow the steps to enable google login from developer console and download the code.
[AndroidHive Google+ login](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Sorry! my mistake, have updated the links.

Comment: This is the exact solution i was looking for :) thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use a **Google** account, not a *Gmail* account. See the [Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html) tutorial and the attached example.

Comment: yeah.but i wanted to get a working example which i can use to refer.So i used this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/ and it worked.Thanks for ur reply anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then you can use the sample example provide by Google itself.

Navigation

- Create New Project

  New Android Sample Project - > Android 5.0.1 -> auth > gau [Google
  Play services,rev 22]

Go through it.